# jsgrid field "required" inside dialog doesn't work

Tags: javascript, validation, dialog, field, jsgrid

I want to set the field with `name: "Name"` as `required` and I inserted : `validate: "required"` according to the jsgrid documentation([http://js-grid.com/docs/#grid-fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLViN.png)) but it doesn't work.

When inserting `validate: "required"` in my below code for jsgrid field: `Name` jsgrid doesn't take the required limitation and inserting blocks!!
I am almost sure that the fact that I enclose my grid inside a dialog creates the problem since `validate` is a parameter that can be defined both in dialog and jsgrid.

This is the code with dialog, in  which I successfully display my grid inside a dialog but I cannot pass validate:"required". I also uploaded and a screenshot[Grid inside dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLViN.png) :

```
$( "#DataGrid" ).dialog({minWidth: 1000, minHeight: 500});
            $("#DataGrid").jsGrid({
                    height: "100%",
                    width: "70%",
                    filtering: true,
                    editing: true,
                    inserting: true,
                    sorting: true,
                    paging: true,
                    autoload: true,
                    pageSize: 15,
                    pageButtonCount: 5,
                    datatype: "json",
                    deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the client?",
                    controller: db,
                    fields: [
                        { name: "Id", align: "center", width: 45 },
                        { name: "Name", validate:"required," align: "center", type: "text", width: 45 },
                        { name: "Displayed Name(locale)", align: "center", type: "text", width: 40 },
                        { name: "Data Type", align: "center", type: "select", items: db.dataType, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name", width: 40 },
                        { name: "Initial Value", align: "center", type: "text", width: 40 },
                        { name: "Initial State", align: "center", type: "select", items: db.initialState, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name", width: 50 },
                        { name: "Worklist Order", align: "center", type: "number", width: 20 },
                        { name: "DB Datatype", align: "center", type: "text", width: 25 },
                        { name: "Allowed Values JSON", align: "center", type: "text", width: 20 },
                        { name: "Allowed Values SQL", align: "center", type: "text", width: 20 },
                        { type: "control", width: 25 }
                    ]

            });
```

I tried the jsgrid code without dialog and it works but how will it work inside the dialog?
This code without dialog works:

```
 $("#DataGrid").jsGrid({
                height: "100%",
                width: "70%",
                filtering: true,
                editing: true,
                inserting: true,
                sorting: true,
                paging: true,
                autoload: true,
                pageSize: 15,
                pageButtonCount: 5,
                datatype: "json",
                deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the client?",
                controller: db,
                fields: [
                    { name: "Id", align: "center", width: 45 },
                    { name: "Name", validate:"required", align: "center", type: "text", width: 45 },
                    { name: "Displayed Name(locale)", align: "center", type: "text", width: 40 },
                    { name: "Data Type", align: "center", type: "select", items: db.dataType, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name", width: 40 },
                    { name: "Initial Value", align: "center", type: "text", width: 40 },
                    { name: "Initial State", align: "center", type: "select", items: db.initialState, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name", width: 50 },
                    { name: "Worklist Order", align: "center", type: "number", width: 20 },
                    { name: "DB Datatype", align: "center", type: "text", width: 25 },
                    { name: "Allowed Values JSON", align: "center", type: "text", width: 20 },
                    { name: "Allowed Values SQL", align: "center", type: "text", width: 20 },
                    { type: "control", width: 25 }
                ]

        });
```

Any ideas please? It is a complex issue.

Comment: Are you trying to show the grid inside a dialog? Try to wrap the grid with another div and initialize dialog on this wrapper.

Comment: @tabalin I really count on you. Listen please: 1)When both my grid and my dialog are wrapped in the same div my grid is successfully displayed inside a dialog but I can't pass (validate: "required") since  then my grid insert action blocks.2) When I wrap my grid and dialog in different grids only an empty dialog is displayed. What should I do please?

Comment: I also uploaded a screenshot in which I show you how my grid is displayed inside my dialog here http://i.stack.imgur.com/yLViN.png. Keep in mind that inserting blocks after validate:"required"

Comment: OK we have a problem. jsGrid validate: "required" doesn't work if I display jsGrid without the dialog. It has the same functionality(it doesn't make a new insertion) which means that the problem lies in my jsGRID implementation. Do you want me to show you the code of my jsgrid db?

Comment: What version of js-grid do you use? Try to follow the basic example on http://js-grid.com/demos/ `Validation` demo, to be sure validation is working for the basic scenario in your environment.

Comment: You were absolutetly right @tabalin!! I had one less .js archive in my jsgrid dependencies. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: One more question @tabalin please. How to insert both 1)validate message and 2)"required" on text? So far  validate: { message: "My message here", validator: function(value) { return value > 0; } },works great for select based on documentation(js-grid.com/docs) but not for text.

Comment: Problem solved. I made a simple function: validate: { message: "My message", validator: function(message) { return message; } },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to @tabalin's help I solved the problem. I had one less jsgrid archive. Now it works like a charm!